# R Aggregation on Year based on Time Interval and Key

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem that I know how to solve in SQL, but not *gracefully* in R.  This seems like a task easily solved with `dpylr`, but I am looking for input.

I have a list of locations which have associated ***start*** and ***end*** times.  These dates mark the period for which the location was *active*.

I want to output a table of all years between an arbitrary interval with `COUNT(active locations)` for each year.  A location is *active* if it was active at any point during that year, and should not be counted more than once.

### Example

Considering the following data:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ LocationID ║ StartDate <POSIXlt> ║ EndDate <POSIXlt>   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 0          ║ 2000-01-01 00:00:00 ║ 2001-01-01 12:00:00 ║
║ 1          ║ 2000-01-01 00:00:00 ║ 2010-01-01 12:00:00 ║
║ 2          ║ 2009-01-01 12:00:00 ║ 2015-06-01 00:00:00 ║
║ 0          ║ 2001-12-01 00:00:00 ║ 2010-01-01 12:00:00 ║
╚════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

The desired output for the year 2000 to 2015 is:

```
╔══════╦═══════════════╗
║ Year ║ Count(active) ║
╠══════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2000 ║ 2             ║
║ 2001 ║ 2             ║
║ 2002 ║ 2             ║
║ 2003 ║ 2             ║
║ 2004 ║ 2             ║
║ 2005 ║ 2             ║
║ 2006 ║ 2             ║
║ 2007 ║ 2             ║
║ 2008 ║ 2             ║
║ 2009 ║ 3             ║
║ 2010 ║ 3             ║
║ 2011 ║ 1             ║
║ 2012 ║ 1             ║
║ 2013 ║ 1             ║
║ 2014 ║ 1             ║
║ 2015 ║ 1             ║
╚══════╩═══════════════╝
```

Any guidance on the best approach would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way. I create a sample data based on your data above. First, I extracted year information from `start` and `end` and create two new columns using `year()`, which you can find in either lubridate or data.table. Then, for each row, I created a sequence of years using `seq()` in `sapply()`. You have a list at this stage. You `unlist()` the list, and count how many times each year appears (`table()`). Finally, you convert the table with `data.frame()`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(ID = c(0,1,2,0),
                   start = as.POSIXct(c("2000-01-01 00:00:00", "2000-01-01 00:00:00",
                                        "2009-01-01 12:00:00", "2001-12-01 00:00:00")),
                   end = as.POSIXct(c("2001-01-01 12:00:00", "2010-01-01 12:00:00",
                                      "2015-06-01 00:00:00", "2010-01-01 12:00:00")))


mutate_each(mydf, funs(year(.)), start:end) -> temp

sapply(1:nrow(temp), function(x){

            seq(temp[x, 2], temp[x, 3], by = 1)}) %>%
unlist %>%
table %>%
data.frame

#      . Freq
#1  2000    2
#2  2001    3
#3  2002    2
#4  2003    2
#5  2004    2
#6  2005    2
#7  2006    2
#8  2007    2
#9  2008    2
#10 2009    3
#11 2010    3
#12 2011    1
#13 2012    1
#14 2013    1
#15 2014    1
#16 2015    1
```

Comment: Thank you; I will try this out and report back if I find any tweaks.

Comment: @DonScott OK. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: So this doesn't actually work on my full dataset.  I am getting weird years in my result 2999 which are not in the original data.  Moreover the counts do not correspond to the real values.

Comment: @DonScott I am sorry to hear that. I wish I can help you, but I do not have your actual data. In your question, you had tables, which does not tell SO users class of each column, for instance. The best thing to do is to use `dput()` and create a minimum example. In that way, you will be able to receive support which would work for your actual dataset.

Comment: With my data, where I need to do the same thing, It can use Jazzurros example just fine. But with my own data I get the error "error in is.finite(if (is.character(from)) from = as.numeric(from else from): default method not implemented for type 'list'".
After some searching, I found out that I needed to convert the data.frame to a matrix with as.matrix(). This solved the problem.